# Craft on Heroku with buckateer as a middleman for Amazon S3

Tags: s3

We are using Craft on Heroku and wants to use S3. The problem is that we want to use a Heroku element (buckateer) as a middleman. Buckateer only gives you an IAM user without listbuckets permissions. So you get "S3::listBuckets(): [AccessDenied] Access Denied". Is there a smart and easy way to set the bucket manually without going into the core files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution that lets you overwrites the core file S3.php without touching the core files.

By adding this snippet to config/general.php

```
// S3 override  
const BUCKET_NAME = 'YOUR BUCKET NAME';  
require_once('../craft/plugins/gm/S3.php');  

return array(  
   ...  
);
```

And duplicate the S3.php file and add it to the plugins folder you can make the needed changes.

Comment: That is clever. Not clean, but definitely clever.

Comment: I know, but as long as it works and is simple for the front-end developers here.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, there's not a clean way of doing that in Craft 2. What you can do, though, is manually create an entry for the Asset Source in the `craft_assetsources` table in database.

This is [improved](https://github.com/craftcms/docs/blob/master/en/configuration.md#overriding-volume-settings) in Craft 3, so, yay!